# Java Swing: unable to load image using getResource

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource, getresource

I'm trying to isolate where the problem could be when trying to add an image to the class directory. (Doing this so when I export as a runnable JAR, the image is included in the package).

So I've got the strawberry.jpg file sitting in 'C:\Users\sean\workspace\myApps\src\testing'
Could you advise what I'm missing?
Thanks!

```
package testing;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class IconTest {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setTitle("Frame1");
        frame1.setSize(500, 500);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        frame1.setLayout(flo);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            IconTest.class.getResource("strawberry.jpg")));
        frame1.add(label1);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("...")` as in the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.setTitle("Frame1");
    frame1.setSize(500, 500);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    frame1.setLayout(flo);

    InputStream resourceAsStream = IconTest.class.getResourceAsStream("strawberry.jpg");
    Image image = ImageIO.read(resourceAsStream);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    frame1.add(label1);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick - it works! Though I did modify the directory as the above comment to Kennet.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Though the code works in Eclipse, exporting to a Runnable Jar file and executing produces no results - no window and graphic. The same result is seen for another application using the principle you advised above. any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I know the question was asked forever ago but when I have done this in the past I always included the file such as "stawberry.jpg" in the same directory as the "IconTest.java". I did this so that it would be included in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Put the image file in the directory where your compiled classes are located and change the path in yor code by adding "/" before the filename:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
        IconTest.class.getResource("/strawberry.jpg")));
```

Resources are searched for in the class path.

Comment: Thanks Kennet. I tried that, but still received "source not found" in the debug log. I tried copying the strawberry.jpg file to 'C:\Users\sean\workspace\SM Apps\bin\testing' too.

Comment: Just managed to get the code below to work, though with the modified directory above. :-)